# liferay lucene search not working

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, liferay

I am trying to implement Lucene based indexing and searching in Liferay 6.2. I have a custom service builder entity and I want to be able to search on all the fields of this entity. But the problem is it is not searching on all the indexed fields unless I explicitly type the `field:value` in the search box. It seems like it is just searching on liferay defaults which are

```
Field.ASSET_CATEGORY_TITLES, Field.ASSET_TAG_NAMES, Field.COMMENTS,
Field.CONTENT, Field.DESCRIPTION, Field.PROPERTIES, Field.TITLE,
Field.URL, Field.USER_NAME
```

This is my entity

```
<entity name="Sample" local-service="true" remote-service="true" table="sample">
        <column name="uuid_" type="String" />
        <column name="sampleDbId" type="long" primary="true" />
        <column name="sampleCollectionDbId" type="long" />
        <column name="biobankDbId" type="long" />
        <column name="hashedSampleId" type="String" />
        <column name="hashedIndividualId" type="String" />
        <column name="materialType" type="String" />
        <column name="container" type="String" />
        <column name="storageTemperature" type="String" />
        <column name="sampledTime" type="Date"/>
        <column name="anatomicalPartOntology" type="String" />
        <column name="anatomicalPartOntologyVersion" type="String" />
        <column name="anatomicalPartOntologyCode" type="String" />
        <column name="anatomicalPartOntologyDescription" type="String" />
        <column name="anatomicalPartFreeText" type="String" />
        <column name="sex" type="String" />
        <column name="ageLow" type="long" />
        <column name="ageHigh" type="long" />
        <column name="ageUnit" type="String" />
        <column name="diseaseOntology" type="String" />
        <column name="diseaseOntologyVersion" type="String" />
        <column name="diseaseOntologyCode" type="String" />
        <column name="diseaseOntologyDescription" type="String" />
        <column name="diseaseFreeText" type="String" />
        <column name="countryOfOrigin" type="String" />
        <finder name="uuid" return-type="Collection">
            <finder-column name="uuid_" />
        </finder>

</entity>
```

I have successfully indexed all the fields that I want to search and I can see it in Luke.

I am indexing it in my indexer as below:

```
@Override
    protected Document doGetDocument(Object obj) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("-----doGetDocument called------");
        Sample sample = (Sample)obj;

        Document document = getBaseModelDocument(PORTLET_ID, sample);

        if(sample.getSampleCollectionDbId() > 0){
            document.addText("sampleCollectionName", SampleCollectionLocalServiceUtil.getSampleCollection(sample.getSampleCollectionDbId()).getName());
        }
        document.add(new Field("biobankName", BiobankGeneralInformationLocalServiceUtil.getBiobankGeneralInformation(sample.getBiobankDbId()).getBiobankName()));
        document.add(new Field("materialType", sample.getMaterialType()));
        //document.addText("biobankName", BiobankGeneralInformationLocalServiceUtil.getBiobankGeneralInformation(sample.getBiobankDbId()).getBiobankName());
        //document.addKeyword("materialType", sample.getMaterialType());
        document.addKeyword("container", sample.getContainer());
        document.addText("storageTemperature", sample.getStorageTemperature());
        document.addDate("sampledTime", sample.getSampledTime());
        document.addText("anatomicalPartOntology", sample.getAnatomicalPartOntology());
        document.addKeyword("anatomicalPartOntologyVersion", sample.getAnatomicalPartOntologyVersion());
        document.addKeyword("anatomicalPartOntologyCode", sample.getAnatomicalPartOntologyCode());
        document.addText("anatomicalPartOntologyDescription", sample.getAnatomicalPartOntologyDescription());
        document.addText("anatomicalPartFreeText", sample.getAnatomicalPartFreeText());
        document.addKeyword("sex", sample.getSex());
        document.addNumber("ageLow", sample.getAgeLow());
        document.addNumber("ageHigh", sample.getAgeHigh());
        document.addText("ageUnit", sample.getAgeUnit());
        document.addText("diseaseOntology", sample.getDiseaseOntology());
        document.addKeyword("diseaseOntologyVersion", sample.getDiseaseOntologyVersion());
        document.addKeyword("diseaseOntologyCode", sample.getDiseaseOntologyCode());
        document.addText("diseaseOntologyDescription", sample.getDiseaseOntologyDescription());
        document.addText("diseaseFreeText", sample.getDiseaseFreeText());
        document.addKeyword("countryOfOrigin", sample.getCountryOfOrigin());

        return document;
    }
```

I have also defined the Hits search method in my localserviceimpl class:

```
public Hits search(long companyId, String keywords) throws SearchException{
        System.out.println("-----SampleLocalServiceImpl search called------");

        SearchContext searchContext = new SearchContext();
        searchContext.setAndSearch(false);


        Map<String, Serializable> attributes = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

        attributes.put("sampleCollectionName", keywords);
        attributes.put("biobankName", keywords);
        attributes.put("materialType", keywords);
        attributes.put("container", keywords);
        attributes.put("storageTemperature", keywords);
        attributes.put("sampledTime", keywords);
        attributes.put("anatomicalPartOntology", keywords);
        attributes.put("anatomicalPartOntologyVersion", keywords);
        attributes.put("anatomicalPartOntologyCode", keywords);
        attributes.put("anatomicalPartOntologyDescription", keywords);
        attributes.put("anatomicalPartFreeText", keywords);
        attributes.put("sex", keywords);
        attributes.put("ageLow", keywords);
        attributes.put("ageHigh", keywords);
        attributes.put("ageUnit", keywords);
        attributes.put("diseaseOntology", keywords);
        attributes.put("diseaseOntologyVersion", keywords);
        attributes.put("diseaseOntologyCode", keywords);
        attributes.put("diseaseOntologyDescription", keywords);
        attributes.put("diseaseFreeText", keywords);
        attributes.put("countryOfOrigin", keywords);

        searchContext.setAttributes(attributes);
        searchContext.setCompanyId(companyId);
        searchContext.setKeywords(keywords);
        System.out.println(searchContext.getAttributes());

        QueryConfig queryConfig = new QueryConfig();

        queryConfig.setHighlightEnabled(false);
        queryConfig.setScoreEnabled(false);
        //searchContext.setAttribute("materialType:", keywords);
        searchContext.setQueryConfig(queryConfig);

        System.out.println(searchContext.getCompanyId());
        Indexer indexer = IndexerRegistryUtil.nullSafeGetIndexer(
                Sample.class);
        System.out.println("-----SampleLocalServiceImpl search called------"+indexer.getFullQuery(searchContext));
        System.out.println("-----SampleLocalServiceImpl search called------"+indexer);


        return indexer.search(searchContext);
    }
```

I am calling this search method from my jsp via localserviceutil class.

So when I type `blood` in the search box, i get no results but when I type `materialType:blood` I get the results back.

- For emtpy search, the query log gives me
  `+(+((+(entryClassName:com.xxx.portlet.xxx.model.Sample))))` (gives full result set)
- If I type blood, the query log gives me

  `+(+((+(entryClassName:com.xxx.portlet.xxx.model.Sample)))) +(assetCategoryTitles:*blood* assetTagNames:*blood* comments:blood content:blood description:blood properties:blood title:blood
     url:blood userName:*blood*)`

  (empty result set)
- If I type materialType:blood, the query log gives me 
  `+(+((+(entryClassName:com.xxx.portlet.xxx.model.Sample))))
  +(materialType:*blood* materialType:blood)` (matching result set)

What I want is the user to be able to just type free text in the box and to get back the matching results. But at the moment this is not working as free text search is just searching on the liferay default fields. How can I fix this?

The question is also posted [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/61581527).

Comment: What makes you think, that `SearchContext.attributes` and `Document.fields` map to the same? You should check the `search` method of your indexer to understand how it is mapping the search context to fields.

Comment: You mean the BaseIndexer which I am extending.

Comment: I see ultimately ´LuceneIndexSearcher.search´ being called where Facets are being used. Do I have to use facet to make this work? I was following the liferay documentation of Searching and Indexing, where no facet has been used.

Comment: You don't need facets (although they support filtering as well), but you need to build the query in your indexer from the attributes. Look at the `JournalArticleIndexer` and how he is mapping the attributes "ddmStructureFieldName" and "ddmStructureFieldValue" to a field from a journal article structure.

Comment: I see I can use `TermQuery, BooleanQuery`, but I don't know where searchContext.setAttributes(attributes); is being used. Also I thought I can also type in Lucene syntax in the search box e.g. `blood OR serum`. But does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not enough to set `searchContext.setAttributes(attributes);` in the `Hits search method` of `localserviceimpl` class. I also had to override the `postProcessSearchQuery` method in my `indexer` class. So after adding the following method in my `indexer` class, I got it working.

```
    @Override
    public void postProcessSearchQuery(BooleanQuery searchQuery, SearchContext searchContext)
        throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-----postProcessSearchQuery called------");

        addSearchTerm(searchQuery, searchContext, "sampleCollectionName", true);
        addSearchTerm(searchQuery, searchContext, "biobankName", true);
        addSearchTerm(searchQuery, searchContext, "materialType", true);
        addSearchTerm(searchQuery, searchContext, "container", true);
        addSearchTerm(searchQuery, searchContext, "storageTemperature", true);
        .....
        .....

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> params =
            (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>)searchContext.getAttribute("params");

        if (params != null) {
            String expandoAttributes = (String)params.get("expandoAttributes");

            if (Validator.isNotNull(expandoAttributes)) {
                addSearchExpando(searchQuery, searchContext, expandoAttributes);
            }
        }
    }
```